# Why does ManagedChannelBuilder not have TLS parameters for making TLS connections to the server?

Tags: java, ssl, grpc

In this example https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/interop-testing/src/test/java/io/grpc/testing/integration/TlsTest.java you see that the TLS client connection has various TLS parameters such as

```
        .negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS)
        .sslContext(sslContext)
```

But my app has thus far used https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.java which by default seems to support TLS. The only parameter it takes is "usePlaintext" which can turn off TLS.

Note: I have installed OpenSSL on the machine, as recommended by https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html

This page does state:

> If the issuing certificate authority is not known to the client then a properly configured SslContext or SSLSocketFactory should be provided to the NettyChannelBuilder or OkHttpChannelBuilder, respectively.

So perhaps you can only use `ManagedChannelBuilder` when the issuing ca is known to the client... but I'm not sure what that means. Perhaps it means the cacert is on the jvm's keystore?

Why do I not have to specify TLS parameters on a `Managed` channel builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Since grpc-java v1.37.0, `TlsChannelCredentials` and `TlsServerCredentials` provide options necessary for configuring TLS in the majority of circumstances, such that only rarely should the transport-specific APIs be necessary. Since `TlsChannelCredentials` and `TlsServerCredentials` are stable APIs and can be used with the stable `ManagedChannelBuilder` API, they should be preferred over the unstable transport-specific APIs.

---

TLS configuration is complex and dependent on the implementation, and `ManagedChannelBuilder` can be used with things other than TLS. Thus, `ManagedChannelBuilder` only has coarse configuration of TLS (on/off). This works well in the common web browser TLS situation of 1) no client certificate and 2) the server certificate is signed by a CA that chains to a root CA in the client's trust store.

However, there is more specific configuration available on `NettyChannelBuilder` and `OkHttpChannelBuilder`. How to configure TLS is different for each, because the implementation is different. The `sslContext` from your first code snippet is a Netty object; that obviously would be poor configuration in `OkHttpChannelBuilder`.

`ManagedChannelBuilder` isn't supposed to have "all the options." It's supposed to have common options that exist across the transport implementations. More specific options are available on the specific transport implementation builders like `NettyChannelBuilder` and `OkHttpChannelBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

[Eric Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690866/eric-anderson) mentioned that we can use `TlsChannelCredentials` and `TlsServerCredentials` since `grpc-java v1.37.0`, and there is how we can do it for `gRPC` client:

```java
    private ServiceGrpc.ServiceBlockingStub client() {
        ChannelCredentials credentials = TlsChannelCredentials.newBuilder()           
                //You can use your own certificate here .trustManager(new File("cert.pem"))
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE.getTrustManagers()) 
                .build();
        ManagedChannel channel = Grpc.newChannelBuilderForAddress("localhost", 443, credentials)
                                     .build();
        return ServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    }
```

Hope it helps somebody.