# What is the difference between NettyChannelBuilder and ManagedChannelBuilder

Tags: netty, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-go

I am trying to understand the difference between ManagedChannelBuilder and NettyChannelBuilder. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353718/why-does-managedchannelbuilder-not-have-tls-parameters-for-making-tls-connection) question but it only mentions details related to TLS configurations. Can someone explain the basic difference between the two?

According to the NettyChannelBuilder [documentation](https://appdoc.app/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-netty/1.10.1/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder.html), it uses Netty transport. What transport medium does the ManagedChannelBuilder use?

Answer (score 4):

`ManagedChannelBuilder` is an abstract class and there are concrete implementations like `NettyChannelBuilder` and `OkHttpChannelBuilder`. When you use an API like `ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget()` or `Grpc.newChannelBuilder()` gRPC finds an appropriate concrete implementation based on your platform and returns it (normally OkHttp on Android; Netty otherwise).

The `OkHttpChannelBuilder` and `NettyChannelBuilder` APIs have more configuration options, but have no guaranteed API stability. This is because they expose options specific to the implementation and if the implementation changes (e.g., from Netty 4 to Netty 5) they may need to be changed or replaced. Because of this, you should prefer using `ManagedChannelBuilder` when able.

There are also concrete implementations that won't be returned by `ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget()`, like `InProcessChannelBuilder`, `CronetChannelBuilder`, and `AndroidChannelBuilder`. These are more specialized, either not "general purpose" or require additional configuration to work.

Answer (score 1):

`ManagedChannelBuilder` is a abstract class which define the behavior, and the `NettyChannelBuilder` is subclass of `ManagedChannelBuilder`, to determine detail of implementation，it use netty as transport; And the `OkHttpChannelBuilder` is another implementation which use OkHttp as transport.

When application startup, will load `ManagedChannelBuilder` implemetation by SPI, if you use `io.grpc:grpc-netty` as dependency, the `NettyChannelBuilder` will be used, if you don't have transport dependency, the application will start failed by `io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException` to ask add one of `grpc-okhttp`, `grpc-netty`, `grpc-netty-shaded` as dependency.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out but still didn't understand what details are different between the two?

While NettyChannelBuilder uses Netty as the transport medium, what transport mode does the ManagedChannelBuilder use, because we can directly use the ManagedChannelBuilder as well.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I add more comment for your question